# SQL Merge two tables - Order BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-order-by, union-all

I have one data table like below.

```
Select * from TBL_01
```

```html
Week     Group
Overall  Nicol  
Overall  Julie
Overall  Kelly
```

```
Select * from TBL_02
```

```html
Week     Group
Week1    Nicol
Week1    Julie
Week1    Kelly
Week2    Nicol
Week2    Julie
Week2    Kelly
Week3    Nicol
Week3    Julie
Week3    Kelly
```

I need to get a result table like below

```html
Week     Group
Overall  Nicol  
Overall  Julie
Overall  Kelly
Week3    Nicol
Week3    Julie
Week3    Kelly
Week2    Nicol
Week2    Julie
Week2    Kelly
Week1    Nicol
Week1    Julie
Week1    Kelly
```

Here the trickey park here is I need to *over by week*, If I do Union all of mth these tables and do  *order by desc* for resulting table. It will order as **overall, week1, week2 and week3**.

But I need to order by **Overall,week3,week2 and week1**

Appreciate your responses.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is option using a case expression to control the ordering.

```
order by case [Week] 
    when 'Overall' then 1
    when 'Week3' then 2
    when 'Week2' then 3
    when 'Week1' then 4
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` and then `order by`:

```
select week, grp
from ((select week, grp from tbl_01) union all
      (select week, grp from tbl_02)
     ) t
order by charindex(week, 'Overall,Week3,Week2,Week1')
```

I find that `charindex()` for this purpose is simpler than a massive `case` statement.

Comment: should week not be in that charindex rather than grp?

Comment: @GordonLinoffIf we have Week10 ,Week 11, then would it be week11,week10..........week2,week1